# getSelectOptions throws an error when a space is used

Tags: selenium-rc, junit4

When a space is present as an option in the drop-down, getSelectOptions fails. See the code below.

```
assertEquals(" ,Half,3 Quarter,Full,1.5", join(selenium.getSelectOptions(
    "//*[@id='xtolform_w[PRI][XTOL_BATH].fdeList[0].id']"), ','));
```

There is another part in our app where these options are seen again, but without the first selection option. This same piece of code, minus the first option, works just fine.

Is there a way to handle this issue that anyone knows of?

Answer (score 0):

did you verify returned values that getSelectOptions() function is called with out assertEquals? Does it include space also?

Comment: Yes, it is returning the space as well. This was my console output:

` `
`Half`
`3 Quarter`
`Full`
`1.5`